# Using Flask, trying to get AJAX to update a span after updating mongo record, but it's opening a new page

Tags: python, mongodb, jquery, flask

Feel like I am stumbling over something fairly simple here.

I am not understanding something about AJAX and Flask.

I have a project wherein I display mongodb records in the browser, which has been working fine.

I added functionality for users to increment votes on a record; to Vote it up if they like it. But originally I was then refreshing the entire page with the new vote, using a redirect, which is clumsy. So I am trying to get AJAX to send the data over to the mongodb record and then update the span where I want the votes to appear without having to reload the entire page.

Problem is, the setup I have going, while still updating the record, is now loading a new page with the HTML i want returned only to the span where the vote tally should be (that is, it's loading a new page with only the word "test" in it (the test value I am currently returning)).

The jQuery (the library I am using) is loading fine and there are no other problems (as far as I can tell).

I have the relevant HTML and JS here:

```
<!-- All Standard HTML up here, removed for simplicity -->


<script>


  $('#vote_link').bind('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var url = $(this).attr('href');
     $('#vote_tally').load(url);

  });


</script>



<a href='/vote_up/{{ item._id }}' id='vote_link'>Vote for Me!</a><br>
Likes: <span id='vote_tally'>{{ item.votes }}</span>


<!-- All Standard HTML down here, removed for simplicity -->
```

and the python is here:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, flash, jsonify
#from mongokit import Connection, Document
#from flask.ext.pymongo import PyMongo
from pymongo import Connection#, json_util
#from pymongo.objectid import ObjectId #this is deprecated
import bson.objectid

'''my pymongo connection - removed for simplicity'''

'''bunch of other routes - also removed for same reason'''


#increment a vote
@app.route('/vote_up/<this_record>')
def vote_up(this_record):

  vandalisms.update({'_id':bson.objectid.ObjectId(this_record)}, 
            {"$inc" : { "votes": 1 }}, upsert=True)

  '''
  also trying to return value for votes field from mongo record, but one step at a 
  time here
  '''
  #result = vandalisms.find({'_id':bson.objectid.ObjectId(this_record)}, {'votes':1})

  result = 'test'

  return result
```

I am also having trouble figuring out how to return the individual vote value for the specified mongodb record back to the browser, even with jsonify (which returns {"votes":'_id'}, but that's another issue. Hopefully someone can help me understand how to make AJAX work for me with Flask in this regard.

Thanks in advance,

**Edit-24Jul2012-2:27PM CST:**

I suspect that the jQuery isn't even activating. It seems to be loading the new page based on the link's href attribute, hence it's no use to have `e.prevenDefault();` when that's not being run. Furthermore, an `alert('I have been clicked');` never runs when the click event takes place.  Again, the jQuery is loaded, but the click event is not activating the jQuery, and I don't know why not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess (based on your edit) is that you have more than one element on the page with the ID of `vote_link` - this is not allowed in HTML (the ID property must be unique across the document).  If you want to have multiple links sharing the same behavior use a class instead (`$(".vote_link")` for example).

Comment: yup. a rookie's mistake. dang.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the way *AJAX* works is that the server replies with XML or JSON.

In this case *jsonify* function from *flask* will respond with a message with this HTTP header field:

```
Content-type: application/json
```

This is inorder for the Browser and JavaScript to understand the syntax, if you need to receive more than just a number or some text.

So, use jsonify on Flask as the docs example and then use $.getJSON() or $.ajax() on the JavaScript side.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/jquery/#json-view-functions

https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/tree/master/examples/jqueryexample

Comment: thanks, i appreciate the explanation, but the changes are still not doing anything to improve the situation. I have to update the original post.